# Python - iterate over pairs

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` and I want to iterate over it like

```
[1,2]
[3,4]
[5,6]
```

I am able to find a lot of answers using `zip()` that result in

```
[1,2]
[2,3]
[3,4]
[4,5]
[5,6]
```

and I could create a new list from this and iterate over every 2nd element in that list with `[::2]` but I am wondering if there is a more elegant solution.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: See the [recipes section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) of the `itertools` documentation, for the `grouper` function.

Comment: `it = iter(lst); list(zip(it, it))`

Answer (score 0):

Using `zip` with a stride of `[::2]` is the most concise way I can think to achieve this.

```
>>> data = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> pairs = [[i,j] for i,j in zip(data[::2], data[1::2])]
>>> pairs
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

Comment: Can't you just do `list(zip(data[::2], data[1::2]))`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `zip`, you can achieve what you want with a simple generator like this:

```
def pairs(iterable):
    for i in range(0, len(iterable), 2):
        yield iterable[i:i+2]
```

Another solution that does not require `iterable` to be indexable or have a known length, and therefore is more general, is to use `iter()`:

```
def pairs(iterable):
    it = iter(iterable)

    while True:
        yield next(it), next(it)
```

This will automatically stop when `next()` raises `StopIteration` to indicate that the iterable doesn't have any more items.

In both of the cases you can then do:

```
for a, b in pairs([1,2,3,4,5,6]):
    print(a, b)
```